# rails how to automatic generate some data to db for developing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

for the develop require ,we always need some fake data, so i want to know is there some way to quick generate data to db, then we can test it as soon as possible

Answer (score 4):

I'd go to factory girl gem, which allows you to create data blueprints to generate data easily:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

or Machinist:
https://github.com/notahat/machinist

I personnaly use Machinist, but I know a lot of people like Factory Girl.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Faker gem ([here is how to do it](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code%3afaker_gemfile))

Comment: The website is http://faker.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Both links dont work

Answer (score 0):

You have a file in you `rails_app/db` directory called `seed.rb` You can put your initial data there.

Have a look at this railscasts [#179 => Seed Data](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data)

After putting dummy data in the file you can run the rake command `rake db:seed` this will put all the contents of your `seed.rb` file in your database and create initial records to play with. :D

Answer (score 0):

Faker is what I generally use to seed the database. Here is the Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial Link on how to set it up.

http://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#cha-updating_showing_and_deleting_users

Section 9.3.2

Also checkout the github page for other options of items you can generate, but this is a great quick and easy how to.